# How to view the source of a non html page?

Tags: firefox, browser, internet-explorer, html

I need to view the source of a webpage. This web page is a plain text page with some text regarding an error. But the page's content type is set to image/jpeg. If I visit the page in Internet Explorer or Firefox, the view source option is greyed out. How can I view the source of pages with content types not set to text/html?

Edit:
**This page is not actually an image, it is a plain text page with the content type of an image.**

Comment: rasheed.kumar, one of the reasons you may not be able to edit your own posts is because you're still unregistered (and/or accessing this from another place). Sign up to Superuser and follow the procedures written in the Help Center to merge this question with your registered account.

Comment: Click somewhere in the page.  Use Ctrl-A to select all.  Ctrl-C to copy.  Paste into Notepad or similar editor.  That assumes it really -is- plaintext and just the content-type is incorrect, though I'm not sure how you can know for sure, if you can't view the source.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. On the serverside, (probably using php or asp), the image is generated and outputted.

As a result, you directly get an image, and an image does not have a textual source. For that raeson, you can't select any text either.

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome you can type (in the address bar)

```
view-source:www.sample.com/image.jpg
```

And it will show you the source.